# anchor vs. javascript reverse scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, anchor

I programmed a website with reverse scrolling using this java script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var winHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pan").height(winHeight);
    $("body").height(winHeight*$(".pan").length);
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function (event) {
    $(".pan").height($(window).innerHeight());
});
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    $(".panelCon").css('bottom',$(window).scrollTop()*-1);
});
```

The only problem that exists is that anchors to an id don't work anymore. It simply doesn't jump to the anchorpoint anymore. Are there any suggestions?

Here's the website: http://www.kleinlautfestival.ch/index2.html on the top (bottom) of the page, there is a yellow arrow with #down.